# Why my Google listing not showing up in maps.google.com search?

Tags: google, google-maps

Why my Google local listing not showing up even if searched with exact title in maps.Google.com?

Its showing mostly results from US when searched.

My [bi solution company map location](http://local.google.co.in/maps/place?hl=en&georestrict=input_srcid:4d9bb2562f6be56e) listing comes up when searched with company name from Google web search, but not showing up in maps.Google.

Is Google places or map listing different from Google local listing?. I have done my listing in Google local. If they are different is there any way to take the local listing to Google place or Google map also.

My listing is a claimed one with 100 percent completed profile details.

Answer (score 1):

Results are ranked based on your search terms plus proximity - relevance and prominence.  Proximity can be determined by your location, your viewport (what map is appearing prior to your keyword search) or your search terms (if you have keywords plus location).

Those factors all contribute to whether or not your listing appears.

Comment: If its as you said i should get my listing when searching from Bangalore/India right, as am having the address in my listing. But it's not showing up when searched from maps.google.com. But it shows up when searched for the company from just Google web search. I was just wondering if i have created listing in Google local, won't it come up in as listed in Google places or Google map location search?. There is no matter with ranking issue as am checking it by querying the right and unique title of my listing.

Comment: When I search [ BDI Systems & Technologies Pvt.Ltd #590, First Floor, 15th Cross Rd, HSR Layout, near BDA complex, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560102] I find your listing.  Any other searches where your listing isn't appearing is a result of ranking issues. Ranking can differ from Google.com.

Comment: K guys, it appears now. Can i ask you something a little diverted but related to maps itself. Why the map is not showing up in [Linkedin BI company profile](http://www.linkedin.com/company/bdi-systems-&-technologies), even-though the address is given proper and listing is there in Google maps?

Comment: Perhaps you can use this, although I am not sure if it is your location: 590, First Floor 15th Cross Road, 15th C Main Road, Bangalore 560034, India